# MS access function vba, macro

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros

I'm having a small issue while making a report in MS Access. I wrote a function in vba, and created a macro to RunCode (the function). So when I execute the Macro, it runs the function and gives me a message box. See Image..

[image: msgbox]

I've researched this and tried SetWarning OFF but it keeps popping up. How do i get rid of this?

Comment: Does the function include a `MsgBox` statement?

Comment: No nothing. I made the function a boolean, is that have anything to do? At the top i do functionname=false and after everythings done functionname=true other than that I'm just taking data from a query, editing it and inserting it into a temp table

Comment: @FatBoySlim7 if you want a better answer than post your code.

Comment: So when you call the function in the Immediate window, it does not display the message box.  Is that correct?  If yes, check where your macro includes a message box "action".

Comment: @Sorceri it's a long functino

Comment: @FatBoySlim7 than all anyone will do is guess at what is going on.  Hard to determine why you get it if we cant see it, so in the end it is left up to you to determine what is causing a message box to show up.  Sorry, I left my crystal ball at home today.

Comment: Either post the relevant portions of your code or figure out how to use the debugger to step through it yourself. Expecting us to guess at where your code might be having a problem is simply unrealistic. We can't debug code we can't see, and this site is not for questions asking us to provide wild lists of guesses at what might be causing the issue. If you want help, provide the information necessary for us to provide it (the code).

Comment: I think it might be the fact that I had an error_handler: (this at top) and error_handler: msgbox err.number & " - " & err.description. i guess its fine now once i commented it out. thanks

Comment: Everyone is so harsh - i bet I'll get blocked on this site because I didn't post code. I know there are times where msgboxes just pop up in access - and there are many different reasons for it. I couldn't find it in my code. I thought someone might give me a hint instead of yelling at me. jesus people relax.

Comment: Hold the phone, Dude!  In the very first comment, I asked if the function includes a `MsgBox` statement and you said no.  `msgbox err.number` **is** a `MsgBox` statement.  It is disingenuous as heck for you to whine that you've been treated harshly.  The quality of help you receive is directly proportional to the quality of the information you provide.  Unfortunately in this situation, it's been too much like "garbage in; garbage out".

Comment: That's okay. People read your question because they want to help. But you need enough data to help. So did you figure it out? If not, please post your code so that we can see and help you.

Comment: @hansup - i didn't realize that would cause the error - I'm not saying anything towards you HansUP you've helped me alot in the past. Just in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, a typical "complete" error handling structure looks e.g. like this:

```
Sub MySub() 

On Error GoTo MySub_Err

    ' Stuff


MySub_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' ... Stuff that always needs to run on exit can go here ...

    ' !! This is the important part that prevents the function 
    ' !! from always running into the error handler:
    Exit Sub

MySub_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Runtime Error " & Err.Number & " in MySub"
    Resume MySub_Exit

End Sub
```

[MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/) can create this structure automatically (but customizable).

Answer (score 1):

error_handler:

Error_handler:
     msgbox err.number & " - " & err.description

this was giving me an error.

I did not do my error_handler: properly (error_handler:). After my function was completed, it would run into error_handler:msgbox err.number & " - " err.description and give me the message box - saying "0 - " because there was no error. I commented it out and everything seems to work okay. Thanks to @HansUp and everyone else for their help.

Comment: Don't worry, you don't get blocked because of a few downvotes.

Comment: Since I started this account - i've had 2 questions with 2 downvotes each, also had one question with 2 downvotes but I deleted it. So all in all 6 downvotes. BTW i'm blocked - or as stackoverflow likes to put it "I've reached my question limit"