# Refreshing a Linked Table in MS Access (2013) Not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is an interface I created to help clients switch database links in the event that the IT department decides to change a network name or path.

[image: Browse for new database path]

I'm trying to clean up a routine that I messed up.  It used to work just fine, but now it doesn't refresh, and I can't figure out why.

1) When the user clicks 'Browse' to select a new path for the database, I call this routine:

```
Private Sub cmdBrowsePath_Click()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strNewPath As String


    strFile = GetFilePath("Locate and select the Master Database")

    If strFile <> "" Then


       Me.txtMaster = strFile

       Call ChangeLinkPath("TBL_VERSION_LATEST", Me.txtMaster)

    End If



End Sub
```

2) When a new path is selected, I want the linked table to automatically switch to what the user has selected - and I call a routine called ChangeLinkPath which I call like this:

```
Public Sub ChangeLinkPath(strLinkName As String, strNewPath As String)

On Error GoTo ChangeLinkPath_Err

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim TDF As DAO.TableDef

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set TDF = db.TableDefs(strLinkName)

    If (Mid(TDF.Name, 1, 4) <> "MSys" And Mid(TDF.Name, 1, 4) <> "~TMP") Then
        Debug.Print "Current link: " & TDF.Connect

        TDF.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strNewPath
        TDF.RefreshLink

        db.TableDefs.Refresh

        Debug.Print "AFTER REFRESHING: " & TDF.Connect

    End If

    Set TDF = Nothing

ChangeLinkPath_Err:

Select Case Err.Number

Case 3011
    MsgBox "'" & strLinkName & "' is NOT in this engine. Make sure you point to an engine that has the same tables or DELETE the linked table if you no longer wish to refresh it.  The original link has not been changed.", vbCritical, "Skipping - " & strLinkName


End Select

ChangeLinkPath_Exit:

Set db = Nothing
Set TDF = Nothing

End Sub
```

Everything works EXCEPT the most important part - Changing the link path!

I check the link after I select a new path and it changes only in the textbox, but NOT in the link itself.  When I hover over the link, it still has the old path.  What am I missing?

If I knew, I could get this basic piece to work for changing any link path.

Comment: So your `Debug.Print "AFTER REFRESHING: "` shows the old connect string? Hm. Try removing `db.TableDefs.Refresh`, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Actually, the Debug.Print AFTER REFRESHING doesn't even happen.  db.TableDefs.Refresh was my attempt to see that the code actually makes it through this point.  It seems to just skip it.  So I go to the database window and  I see the old link in the database window when I hover over the link.  I try refresh all and also restarting the database.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Then I suggest a `Case Else  Msgbox Err.Description` in your error handler...

Comment: Andre, great - some progress.  It says "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file C:\Users\Public\Documents\FMTools\SpendPlan - App. It is already opened exclusively, or you need permission... I see that the database I'm trying to point to is missing from the path - I'll check.

Comment: I fixed the path and now the link changes finally, but I still get an error that is blank. Is it because there's no error number?

Comment: I decided to trap an err.number of "0-"  because the current solution seems to work fine.  If someone can tell me what I need to do to clean up the "0-" err.number, I'll gladly fix it.

Comment: 0 means there was no error. Typically you set up an error handler so that it is only reached when there actually is an error. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37010669/3820271

Comment: Where you added `Case Else Msgbox Err.Description` try changing it to `Case Else Msgbox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description` to see if you get an error number.

Comment: Yes, that's how I found out that the error number was "0-" and I wondered why the "on error flag was relevant in the first place. Go figure. Nevertheless, I trapped "0-" and it worked.