# Can't figure out what object is being declared that is not SET

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm getting an error in my Access VBA script that says Error # 91: Object variable or With block variable not set. I searched on the MSDN site and [found the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506(v=vs.60).aspx). It says that I either have an object declared that isn't being `SET` or that I have a `WITH` block variable not `SET`. Seeing as how I don't have a `WITH` block in my script, it must be the first one. But to my still rather naive eyes I am setting all the objects that I'm using. Could someone help me figure out this error?

Side quest: Am I doing error handling correctly? I added that `If` statement because it was giving an error message of `0` every time, so I made it so that it only shows if an `Err.Number > 0` happens.

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()


On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    current_date_time = Now


    If current_date_time = #6/28/2016 8:18:15 AM# Then 

        MsgBox ("the current_date_time variable holds: " & current_date_time)


        Dim dbs As DAO.Database
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
        Dim mail_body As String
        Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim oMail As MailItem

        mail_body = "The following jobs...blah...blah..." & vbCrLf

        Set dbs = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_BMBFLoc")
        Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

        If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then

            rst.MoveFirst
            Do Until rst.EOF = True

                    mail_body = mail_body & rst!job & "-" & rst!suffix & vbCrLf

            rst.MoveNext
            Loop

        End If

        rst.Close
        dbs.Close

        Set rst = Nothing
        Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            oMail.Body = mail_body
            oMail.Subject = "Blah blah"
            oMail.To = "someone@someplace.com" 
            oMail.Send

        Set oMail = Nothing
        Set oApp = Nothing

        End If

ErrorHandler:

    If (Err.Number > 0) Then
        MsgBox ("Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it the `Dim oApp As Outlook.Application` ???

Comment: Maybe you should try `Dim oMail As outlook.MailItem` . I would also check that you have selected the reference to the outlook library which is in `tools>references`

Comment: To debug this: comment out your error handling. Then Access will stop on the offending line.

Comment: [A typical "complete" error handling structure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37010669/3820271) . You version works usually, but not if you ever use `On Error Resume Next` with local error handling before that part runs, because then Err.Number may still be <>0 .

Comment: @LiamH the outlook library is checked.

Comment: You declared `oApp`, but never set it to anything.

Comment: Put `Exit Sub` on the line before `ErrorHandler`.  With that change the `ErrorHandler` code block never runs unless there is an error ... so then you don't need to check whether `Err.Number > 0` --- `Err.Number` has to be non-zero in that case.

Comment: What value do you have for the form's `Timer Interval` property?

Comment: `Form_Timer()` is tricky.  Test your code as the click event of a command button.  Don't bother with `Form_Timer()` until you're positive you've worked out all the bugs with the VBA procedure.

Comment: @HansUp I set it to 1000ms. The end goal is to fire the timer event every Monday at 06:15:00 AM and send an email if the results of a recordet are not empty.

Comment: Good tip on that `Exit Sub`.

Comment: OK.  Ultimately you will want to check whether `TimeValue(Now()) = #6:15 AM#`,  but don't bother about that just now.  Get the rest of the code working reliably first before you put it into `Form_Timer()` which you're calling every second.

Comment: That was an option I considered, but I.T. is currently very busy with other projects and I want to see if all this can be done with Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would have the following line:

```
dim oMail as outlook.mailItem
```

You then need to set `OApp` before you set the `oMail`:

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
```

If you find yourself getting run-time error 287 on the send action, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36328068/5043393).

A standard error handler I would use, is like so:

```
errHandler:
        Dim msg As String
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
               msg = "email Form Timer Error #" & Str(Err.Number) & " error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
               MsgBox msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
        End If
        Exit Sub
```